# Jenkins CI/CD deployment to AWS EKS without Docker registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-registry, nexus3, amazon-eks

We are trying to setup a development CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins that builds the Docker Images and deploy that Directly to AWS EKS cluster. Is this even possible??

**Our Existing system**

- Jenkins as CI to pick the Code from GitLab and Build Docker Image
- After Build, Jenkins push the Image to Jfrog Artifactory(Professional)
- We use Harness for CD, that picks the Image from Artifactory and deploy that
  to AWS

Here, Artifiactory and Harness Incurs cost for us and we don't want to use that for Development builds. So, we have setup a Docker Registry with Soantype Nexus3 OSS(open source version).

I would like to know two Options here:

1. if I can use Jenkins to Build Docker Image and Push that to Nexus Docker Registry and Use Jenkins Itself for CD to deploy that to AWS EKS?
2. Build Docker images with Jenkins and directly deploy that to AWS EKS without even having to store it in a docker registry?

Any suggestions and help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the first option much better.

because one day may need roll-back docker image on Kubernetes. (even development environment)

or you can use AWS ECR. it's easier to use on EKS.

and I think ECR is cheaper than Nexus operation cost.

Answer (score 0):

You may be happy to know that Harness has created a free software version of it's CD service, called Harness [Continuous Delivery Community Edition](https://github.com/harness/harness-cd-community), which should work nicely for your development builds.